# Resize container, not output image - Croppa Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have to crop an image for a carousel in a form , the croppa container has 300*167 px (to fit the form). If I resize the output image with "quality" prop, the image quality is loss by strech it. Is there a way that I can resize the container but not the output image?

I mean, I want to conserve the original proportional size of the image, only resizing the croppa container to fit the forms, like reduce by scale it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3jbZ.png)

Comment: I am not very sure of what you are asking, if you are okay to share your screen on skype, then ping me on syed_haroon

Comment: Hi Syed! thanks you but I not use skype! I appreciate your help anyway. I've uploaded a img to try explain.

Comment: With proposition to 300*167 cropping - what is the final size of image you are expecting?

Comment: Can you please let me know - did my Answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda hack: say that you need the final size of the cropped item to be 1150X640 which is propositional scale to 300*167, here is what I am doing: Using `transform: scale();` to scale the child `div` proportionally to it's parent.

```js
var cropViewerWidth = 300;
var cropViewerHeight = 167;

// size need to be proportionate to above width and height
var cropWrapperWdith = 1150;
var cropWrapperHeight = 640

const scale = Math.min(
  cropViewerWidth / cropWrapperWdith,    
  cropViewerHeight / cropWrapperHeight
);

const cropWrapper = document.getElementById('jsCropWrapper'); 
cropWrapper.setAttribute('style', 'transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(' + scale + ')');
```

```css
.crop-viewer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 167px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.croppa-wrapper {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1150px;
  height: 640px;
  background-color: blue;
  /* If you are sure with scale factor then use mannuly here and don't use JS  */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.26086); */ 
  position: relative;
}

/* just style stuff */
.text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-wrapper > div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='jsCropViewer' class='crop-viewer'>
  <div id='jsCropWrapper' class='croppa-wrapper'>
    <! –– add you croppa component here ––>
    <div class='text-wrapper'>
      <div>
        <div>I am 1150x640</div>
        <div>But, I look like: 300x167</div>
        <div>Scaled val is 0.26086</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```